# How to make a regular expression which doesn't match any words

Tags: regex

in python code

```
regular_expression = ""
p = re.compile(regular_expression)
result = p.match("some strings")

if result:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

I want to make regular_expression which always can't find match in any situation.
I though ""(no words) would work. but sadly it always return "Match".
I also want to know why it works like that. how "" and ".*" can be same?

Comment: Hint: Try `print(result.group())` to see *what* was actually matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple regex is

```
(?!)
```

meaning "Assert that it's impossible to match the empty string".

Your "empty regex" always matches precisely because it's always possible to match the empty string. `.match()` does not require the regex to match the *entire* string, it only requires that it should match at the start of the string, which it does.

If you want the regex to match the entire string, then use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
regular_expression = r"\A\Z"
```

only matches an empty string.

**EDIT:**

In most regex flavors, `\z` is the true end-of-string anchor whereas `\Z` can also match before a final newline character at the end of the string. In Python however, `\Z` behaves as a true end-of-string anchor.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of expressions which will never match anything.
For example `^(?<=.).` (match a character at the start of the string with any preceding character).

Comment: You can even drop the second `.`.

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty strange request, could you explain why you need that?

In any case, the expression "" matches anything because the requirement is that the regex should be present *somewhere* in the given string, and the empty string is present in *every string* - if you're familiar with set theory in math, this is similar to how every set contains the null set {}.

Now, there are several ways you could go about to get a regex that matches nothing; the first one that comes to my mind is "$abc". This requires the string to contain "abc" *after* the **end** of the string, which is impossible, hence no string can satisfy this regex.

Answer (score -1):

How about "$^" (End of line, then Begining of line) ?

Comment: This matches the empty string.and is therefore unsuitable.